# Bad_Request while entering the right criidentials razorpay in curl request

Tags: razorpay

I'm new to Razorpay. I'm looking for `POST` a plan for customer API. Finally, I reached [link](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/subscriptions/#create-a-plan). In that, you find the console `request`-`response`. When I'm hitting the curl request by entering my `KEY_ID` and `KEY_Secret` then it shows me the below error

```
{"error":{"code":"BAD_REQUEST_ERROR","description":"The requested URL was not found on the server.","metadata":{}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error. In my case, the issue was with the callback_url. Make sure to assign a hosted url as callback_url/cancel_url. If you are working on localhost, then redirecting to one of the page in your project would result in this error.